# Automatically getting a value from a table

Tags: ms-access

In MS Access, I have t1(table) with two columns (product, price)
And I have t2 with (product, price, quantity, total)
I made a relationship between product in t1 with product in t2 (one-to-many) then I created a form for t2 and replace product field with combobox list.
I need to automatically get price from t1.price when I choose a product in combobox, how can I do that?
Thanks for all of you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use code in combobox AfterUpdate event to populate T2.price field. Make combobox multi-column. Code references combobox column with price. Reference columns by index. Index begins with 0 so if price is in second column, its index is 1.

`Me.Price = Me.cbxProduct.Column(1)`

Advise not to have exactly same field name in multiple tables.